# Revert to universal storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

Here is what's happened:

1. Created an app with many view controllers
2. Configured element placement and constraints in the "Any, Any" size class storyboard.
3. Accidentally configured element placement and constraints in a few view controllers in the "Compact, Regular" size class storyboard.
4. Now when I make changes in "Any, Any", the locations and constraints in the "Compact, Regular" storyboard don't change.

How do I revert all of my view controllers to the "Any, Any" universal storyboard and dump all of the changes I've accidentally made in the other size classes?

Comment: You might need to re-add constraints, you can clear all the constraints for that particular viewcontroller by selecting menu option `Editor->Resolve Autolayout Issues -> (All Views in ViewController Section) -> Clear Constraints` then re-add.

Comment: I think that worked!  Thanks.

Comment: OK this didn't work after all.  I have a view controller where everything looks the way I want it to in Any,Any.  But when I switch to Compact, Regular, it is all jumbled up.

I tried to erase the constraints on all configurations.  Then I tried to move things around in Any, Any, but the changes weren't reflected in Compact, Regular.

So how do I get my storyboard config "unstuck" and make all the other views adopt their config from Any, Any?